# Symfony form validation to accept miliseconds

Tags: php, symfony

Hey I'm sending a date via API, nextly it's in the `yyyy-MM-dd H:i:s.u` format, sadly I can't make my form validation to let it go throught. Seems the format passed to form is not working.

```
$builder
    ->add('partnerId', NumberType::class)
    ->add('price', NumberType::class)
    ->add('measurementTime', DateType::class,[
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'html5' => false,
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s.u',
        ]
    );
```

Anyone got an idea what I'm missing?

Comment: as far as I can tell from the source none of the date and time types in the form component support milliseconds at all (I mean, to be fair, people *usually* don't enter times with that precision ^^). You probably have to implement this yourself or find a library that does.

Comment: Ahh oki. I'm trying badly to find a way to make it work, well. thanks :)

Comment: By the way, maybe there is a way to make it work with ```'format' => 'U.u'```?

Comment: mh, I just noticed you're using DateType and not DateTimeType. But I have doubts it changes anything, tbh.

Comment: Yeah... I did try with DateTimeType too but.. eh. I'm starting to hate symfony :P